# Alternative to Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm

Tags: matlab, levenberg-marquardt

I have recieved some old code which uses the function fmincon and the algorithm LevenbergMarquardt to optimize my parameters. However this algorithm is no longer available in this function. 
Since I am new to Matlab I am not sure about what the best alternative is.
I have tried to simply change the function to the ones that are compatible with LevenbergMarquardt but this doesn't seem to work.

Below are the vector of options and the fmincon function. "S", "A" and "b" are starting values for the parameters, "lb" and "ub" are upper and lower bounds.

Please write if anything is unclear or you you need additional information.

```
options_ = optimset('LevenbergMarquardt', 'on','TolFun',1e-6,'TolX',1e-6, 'HessUpdate', 'steepdesc', 'Display','iter', 'LargeScale', 'off', 'MaxFunEvals', 100000, 'MaxIter', 100000);

[ out_p, fval, exitfflag ] = fmincon(@MyLikelihoodFunction, S, A, b, [], [], lb, ub, [], options_);
```

Answer (score 0):

What did you try and what went wrong?

I'd start with [fmincon](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) with all default options. That will give you the interior-point algorithm. Set 'Display' to 'iter' to see how the algorithm progresses. If the problem is large (although the old code has 'LargeScale' off), you might try 'HessianApproximation' set to 'lbfgs'.

A and b are not part of the starting point. Those define the linear inequality constraints. There's more info on that in the documentation link I gave above.